# Image/Text Recognition

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I saw that this company Mitek made an app that could read receipts through the iPhone's camera and record the information from them. (http://www.miteksystems.com/OOMPH_MobileReceipt.asp). My assumption would be that they run the images through some kind of image/text recognition software. Any ideas what what they might be using? If theres an API that can interpret text from pictures that would be great to.

cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are probably using  some type of OCR software. It is hard to tell exactly which.

You can look at [ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/), for example

Comment: I've been trying to get ocropus to work since I posted this, but to no avail. The documentation is literally terrible. Any idea where I can find some nice tutorials?

Comment: It took me a while on Ubuntu. I followed this article: http://xplus3.net/2009/03/31/ocr-with-ocropus-and-tesseract/. This was more than 6 months ago so the information can be bit outdated.

Comment: If I recall correctly (this is quite a common question for iPhone, I guess), tesseract compiles and works even on the iPhone. I have to admit that I failed compiling ocropus even on my desktop, but that's not bad as it basically just uses tesseract and adds some google-relevant-page-layout stuff. So: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/
works great, compiles easily, and even helps breaking captchas ;)